# How to return latest row based on userid and date from three tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to query 3 tables and return the latest row based on `userid` and `date`.

Example:

```
Table1, Table2, Table3

wdt_id | userid | date | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5
```

Comment: Possible to query a query? 

This returns three records, I just need to reduce to one.

select wdt_id,userid,date
from table1 where (userid, date) in
(select userid, max(date) as date
from table1
group by userid)
UNION
SELECT wdt_id,userid,date
from table2 where (userid, date) in
(select userid, max(date) as date
from table2
group by userid)
UNION
SELECT wdt_id,userid,date
from table3 where (userid, date) in
(select userid, max(date) as date
from table3
group by userid)

Comment: Welcome. You should edit your original question with all the details, make it clear and include all the info so people can help you, and not add comments like this unless further discussion appears